# How to load Arabic csv to MYSQL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

### i want to load csv arabic file into mysql

I tried the following

```
set session collation_database=utf8_general_ci;
set session character_set_database=utf8 ;
#SET NAMES utf8;
#SET character_set_database=utf8;

LOAD DATA local INFILE "D:\\trade20120314.csv"
INTO TABLE trade
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ;
```

but the arabic columns still appears as 
 "?????? ????????????????".

I am sure that the csv file is encoded to utf8 and the default character set of server and client is as utf8 and also the columns character set and collation as utf8 .

I don't know where is the problem , any suggestions .

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the JDBC URI `?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` (or `&...`). The driver class also has to know the transfer protocol. (Of course the file should be in UTF-8.)